# Doctrine2 / Symfony2 - Using different databases per bundle

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

How can I use different databases in every single bundle of Symfony2 with Doctrine2?

FooBundle <- Database "Foo"

BarBundle <- Database "Bar"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may help [How to work with Multiple Entity Managers and Connections](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html).

So you can define multiple [Entity Managers](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php) related to your databases connections, you can then map your bundle(s) to the right [Entity Manager](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php).

The examples on [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html) are well explained.

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection:   foo_connection
        connections:
            foo_connection:
                # ...
                # Foo connection parameters
                # ...
            bar_connection:
                # ...
                # Bar connection parameters
                # ...

    orm:
        default_entity_manager:   foo_manager
        entity_managers:
            foo_manager:
                connection:        foo_connection
                mappings:
                    FooBundle: ~
            bar_manager:
                connection:       bar_connection
                mappings:
                    BarBundle: ~
```